# Using wget and getting a different outcome than when using a browser

Tags: windows, http, windows-8, httprequest, wget

I am using wget for windows (gnuwin32 wget-1.11.4-1) in Windows 8 and using it for a helpdesk tool called kayako, telling it to poll from an email queue. The command line looks like this:

```
wget.exe -O null --timeout 25 http://xxx.kayako.com/cron/index.php?/Parser/ParserMinute/POP3IMAP
```

I know it takes around 20 seconds to receive a response from the server in my particular case when using a browser with the url in the command line above. However, when using that command, it returns almost immediately. This is an excerpt of the output:

> Connecting to xxx.kayako.com[xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx]:80... connected. HTTP
>   request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK Length: unspecified
>   [text/html]

I would like to know what would be the difference between the two cases and how could I get wget to behave in the same way as the computer (I know it doesn't because kayako is not polling from the email queue).

Comment: Fire up WireShark and see what the differences in the HTTP headers are.

Comment: @Luke thanks good idea, I'll do that and update with a reply if I can solve the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of potential variables, but one of the more common distinctions made by web servers is based on the user agent string you are reporting.  By default, wget will identify itself truthfully as wget.  If this is an issue, you can use the `--user-agent=` option to change the user agent string.

For example, you could identify as Firefox on 64-bit Windows with something like `--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0"`.

Comment: Thanks, that's very good guess! Unfortunately I'm still getting a "200" response from the server almost immediately (it always takes longer on the browser) and it's not working.

Comment: If it's not that or --referer="http://some/site/" then I don't know what else to tell ya